# How to translate card game terms?

Tags: single-word-requests, resources

My apologies if multiple word requests are off topic in [single-word-requests](/questions/tagged/single-word-requests). But all of these words are from a single category and I thought it might be handy to have them together in a single place for future reference. Or perhaps there is a resource listing groups of words by topics like this one that I could refer to?

I'm looking for the translations of these terms:

> to draw, to shuffle, to deal, to place (on a table) face up, to discard, to set aside, a turn, a round, a pile, a hand (a handful of cards)

Most of these have a very broad meaning only including playing cards as a border case, and some of them (e.g., a hand) have an entirely different established meaning unless the context is clearly understood, making my usual dictionary searches impractical, if not prone to wrong results.

If you point me in the right direction and all that's left is a lot of independent lookups I can do the labour myself and self-answer later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provisionally, I would use these terms.

- to draw - preni karton
- to shuffle - miksi kartojn
- to deal - disdoni kartojn
- to place (on a table) face up - elmeti averso-supren
- to discard - formeti
- to set aside - flankenmeti
- a turn - vico
- a round - partio
- a pile - stako
- a hand (a handful of cards) - mano

I found this link via google and it seems to match more or less what I've suggested above.

https://books.google.com/books?id=5-IaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=miksi+kartojn+disdoni&source=bl&ots=tUdkDykPQJ&sig=EnkImxH5rE8hJ2PbxABZtDDuUJ8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwjMbTn6LRAhUD42MKHUnWBrkQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=miksi%20kartojn%20disdoni&f=false

This one here is primarily for poker.

https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pokera_terminaro

And one for bridge

http://lpcs.math.msu.su/~pentus/bd1.htm

Comment: Brilliant answer, as always. Great many thanks!

Comment: Thank you. If anybody notices any errors in my list or inconsistencies between it and the linked articles, please let me know and I'll update my answer appropriately.